# Can't find pydev console prompt in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, console, pydev, prompt

So I'm working on two machines and they both have Eclipse and Pydev on them. The first machine has a console that has a prompt where I can type in and execute commands when I run on:

[image: Preferred Console]

The second machine doesn't have the same prompt and I can't figure out how to get it:

[image: Console that needs to be fixed]

I've been looking around online and the closest piece of advice I found is that I need to find the console button on the menu bar next to the tabs and select to show/hide the prompt, but as you can see it's doesn't show up on the second machine. Does anyone know how to I can get the console prompt on the second machine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue. I was using PyDev 2.8.2 which didn't support the prompt, I updated to 4.5.4 (higher versions don't show up in my eclipse) and now I'm able to see it.